# Mariadb query runs out of memory with use of match() against()

Tags: full-text-search, mariadb, match, match-against, against

I have a very large table (around 50 GB) but with few columns:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_sec BIGINT(20) NULL,
    full_name VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FULLTEXT INDEX fts_full_name (full_name)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

when I execute the following queries:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MATCH(full_name) AGAINST('lastname middle first ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MATCH(full_name) AGAINST('lastname middle first ')

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MATCH(full_name) AGAINST('lastname middle first ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 1000

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MATCH(full_name) AGAINST('lastname middle first ') LIMIT 1000

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MATCH(full_name) AGAINST('lastname middle first ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 100

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MATCH(full_name) AGAINST('lastname middle first ') LIMIT 100
```

Sometimes send me the following error message:

```
SQL Error (128): Table handler out of memory
```

But it does not happen when I execute:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MATCH(full_name) AGAINST('+lastname +middle +first ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MATCH(full_name) AGAINST('+lastname +middle +first ')
```

I have tried with the following values and there is no improvement:

```
--key-buffer-size=20M 
--tmp-table-size=2G 
--thread-pool-max-threads=10 
--max-connections=100 
--max-heap-table-size=2G 
--innodb-buffer-pool-size=4G
```

Does anyone know what could be happening? or how can I correct it?

My server is running in windows 10 (x64), 10.3.12-MariaDB (x64), 32 GB of RAM, core i7

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about the 3 Variables below and experiment with them:

```
| innodb_ft_cache_size            | 8000000    |
| innodb_ft_result_cache_limit    | 2000000000 |
| innodb_ft_total_cache_size      | 640000000  |
```

If you don't have success, then file a bug report at bugs.mysql.com (and post the bug number here).

Comment: Hi @RickJames I've ben reading about the variables, and I tried with: `--innodb-buffer-pool-size=4G` and `--innodb-ft-result-cache-limit=4G` and works smooth. Thank you so much

Comment: Hi @Rick James, I am facing a `Error Code: 188. FTS query exceeds result cache limit`. I have a large instance having 128GB of RAM, so I increased the `innodb_ft_result_cache_limit` to the maximum value, but still I am facing the error. Do you have some suggestions on how to tune the settings to avoid such errors? FYI, `innodb_ft_cache_size` is also set to 4GB.

Comment: @thijsvdp - Does it happen for uncommon names as well as common names?  MariaDB bug reporting:  jira.mariadb.org

Comment: No only for very frequently occuring names. I am searching on company names for example. One example is 'apple inc'. Interestingly, searching on `'"apple inc"'` (exact match), results in this error, whereas searching on `'apple inc'` (and/or match) does not give these errors and works great. Searching on `'+apple +inc'` does not result in errors, but takes much longer. Finally, searching on `'"apple" "inc"'` also gives FTS cache limit errors. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: @thijsvdp - `'"apple inc"'` -- is what you want; what error does it give?  The last two would 'match' "inc apple" or "apple records inc", which you don't want.

Comment: @Rick James - Yes, in this case `'"apple inc"'` is what I want. When searching I get `Error Code: 188. FTS query exceeds result cache limit`. However, I don't understand why `'apple inc'` is fast and does not give the `188` error. It should in theory have more matching results, and therefore sooner reach the cache limit? Or maybe I am misunderstanding how it works.

Comment: @thijsvdp - A guess:  '"apple inc"' needs to find where each word occurs in each document.  Then it merges the lists together to see if the words are adjacent in the right order.  "inc" possible exists in half the documents, often more than once.  So all the pointers might add up to more than 4GB.  Suggest you file a bug report; I have not thought of any further workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

You should set innodb_buffer_pool_size to about 80% of your memory.

This is available for mysql or mariadb.
See mariadb doc for innodb: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_buffer_pool_size

Edit mysql or mariadb config file:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size=50G
```

Restart mysql server